# PayPal Legacy gives error for INR rupee

Tags: php, joomla, paypal, shopping-cart, virtuemart

I am using PayPal Legacy for virtue mart and used in Indian Rupee(INR) currency.

But problem is that. PayPal not Accept INR rupees.

All the functionality is proper working for product and currency go to the add to cart to final checkout .

while redirecting to paypal checkout it gives error message

> "This recipient does not accept payments denominated in INR. Please contact the seller and ask him to update his Payment Receiving Preferences to accept this currency."

Please give me some examples

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

pay pal does not support INR. So you have to convert INR to USD.

You can take a look at: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/currency-rates